# react-router Router.HistoryLocation leaves target with <noscript> but without works perfectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have just left the starting blocks with ReactJs and discovered the react-router. Awesome stuff but i cannot see to get the following code to work with the "Router.HistoryLocation" as the 2nd param to the run function.

It all works perfectly without however uses a # in the url. [This Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router) got me to Router.HistoryLocation as the 2nd param, so do the [github docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router#whats-it-look-like). But when ever i run this in the browser the result is the target filled with nothing more that this:

```
<noscript data-reactid=".0"></noscript>
```

**Here is the code running on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/saxutulaxi/1/.** If you edit the code and remove the "Router.HistoryLocation" from the last bit it all works but with it does not.

Here is the simple script i am running.
    // This is straight from the overview.md in the react-router docs
    var Router = ReactRouter;
    var DefaultRoute = Router.DefaultRoute;
    var Link = Router.Link;
    var Route = Router.Route;
    var RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="calendar">Calendar</Link></li>
                </ul>
            </header>

            {/* this is the important part */}
            <RouteHandler/>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

var Inbox = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                This is the inbox
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Calendar = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                This is the calendar
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}/>
        <Route name="calendar" handler={Calendar}/>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Inbox}/>
    </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function (Handler) {
    React.render(
        <Handler/>,
        document.querySelector('#content')
    );
});
```

Not sure what else to do except ask on here as i think i have followed the guides to the letter...

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, however it won't work on JSBin due to the app being run in an iframe where the url is not what react-router is expecting. In JSBin's case the iframe reports a HistoryLocation of /runner.

`<Route name="app" path="/runner" handler={App} >` fixes your issue on JSBin.

Comment: Perfect thank you very much. I did not realise you had to declare that. For my app to work i wanted to use the react router after the path:  `....com/wish/`. So I had to set the path with a trailing slash:    `path="/wish/"`

Comment: The point is that JSBin, while great, is not always an accurate reflection of what the lib will do when it's on a real page. In this case it's because you are sharing the address bar with JSBin itself.