# Strange navigation issue with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

I have a fairly basic login setup (code below) with a few components requiring authentication. When I navigate to http://localhost:8000/, it redirects to http://localhost:8000/login and everything is fine. If I then log in, it goes back to http://localhost:8000/ and displays my main component.

However, when I navigate to http://localhost:8000/login directly, it says "Cannot GET /login". Same thing with my "about" component. It does work when I add a pound symbol: http://localhost:8000/#/login. Can anyone explain what's going on?

```
var React = require('react');
var Main = require('./components/main');
var Login = require('./components/login');
var About = require('./components/about');
var SessionStore = require('./stores/session-store')
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory';

import { Router, Route, Link, History, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';

var App = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return <div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      }
});

function requireAuth(nextState, replaceState) {
  if(!SessionStore.isLoggedIn()){
    replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/login');
  }
}

function redirectIfLoggedIn(nextState, replaceState){
  if(SessionStore.isLoggedIn()){
    replaceState({ nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }, '/');
  }
}

var routes = (
  <Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Main} onEnter={requireAuth}/>
      <Route path="login" component={Login} onEnter={redirectIfLoggedIn} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
)

React.render(routes, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer, the `http://localhost:8000/#/login` is running in the javascript app in your browser, so the app it's being served from `/` by the express web server, and so the `/`(app)`#/login` and `/#/about` are not requesting anything from the server but are routes in the JS app, (`react-routes`) to render the various components. when you enter `/login` directly it's has to querying the express web server, but you don't have anything express server routes set up except the one to  serve the app at the root `/`.

So it's down to `react-routes`, a related questions asks how to remove it, but please be aware as of Oct '15 `react-router` changed from version 0.13 to 1.0 which changed the API quite a bit, so be careful when reading examples to be aware of the version 
[How to stop /#/ in browser with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router)