# Upgrading React-Router and replacing hashHistory with browserHistory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, phoenix-framework

I have a bootstrap+react theme that was using react-router 1.x and hashHistory and I wanted to remove the hash so followed this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router). 
Initially I tried to do this while having the 1.x version and I was unable to do it so I've decided to upgrade react-router to 2.x.
After installing react-router 2.x the app worked because it was still using hashHistory but when I replaced it with browserHistory:

- it showed a grey screen
- the HTML of the app had only the `<noscript data-reactid=".0"></noscript>` tag inside it
- the React Developer Tools showed me that the router had a `null` inside it
- I also checked the Network tab and all files were downloaded properly, and had the right content
- **surprisingly the was nothing printed in the JavaScript Console, no error/no warnging** (I'm really shocked about this, but I'm new React, I would like to know what to do in situations like this).
  Here are my changes to `Router.jsx`:

  ```
   import React from 'react'
   import {render} from 'react-dom'
  -import {Router} from 'react-router'
  +// import {Router} from 'react-router'
  +import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
  +// import { useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
  +// import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
  +// import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'`

   import History from '../components/layout/navigation/classes/History.js';

   import Routes from './Routes.jsx';

  +// const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false })
  +
   var rootInstance = render((
  -    <Router history={History}>
  +    <Router history={browserHistory}>
           {Routes}
       </Router>
   ), document.getElementById('smartadmin-root'));`
  ```

The backend uses the [Phoenix Framework](http://www.phoenixframework.org/).

**Later Edit**:
Here you have the `hashHistory` version that works

[https://gitlab.com/blockbuster/react-router-2-with-hash-working/tree/master](https://gitlab.com/blockbuster/react-router-2-with-hash-working-public/tree/master)

And here is the `browserHistory` version that doesn't:

[https://gitlab.com/blockbuster/react-router-2-with-browserHistory-not-working/tree/master](https://gitlab.com/blockbuster/react-router-2-with-browserHistory-not-working-public/tree/master)

The react code for both can be found under the `src` directory.

To run the app you need to have `Elixir`, `Phoenix` and Postgresql installed, to get backend dependencies( run `$ mix deps.get`), get frontend dependecies( `npm install` and `bower install`), to change the database username and password in `config/dev.exs`, to create and migrate the database `mix ecto.create && mix ecto.migrate` and finally run `mix phoenix.server`.

Comment: If you could share the code, it would save a lot of time.

Comment: @HazardouS See the edits I made above. Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it this way in your Router.jsx?

```
import React from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, useRouterHistory } from 'react-router'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'

import History from '../components/layout/navigation/classes/History.js';

import Routes from './Routes.jsx';

const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({ queryKey: false })

var rootInstance = render((
    <Router history={appHistory}>
        {Routes}
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('smartadmin-root'));
```

Comment: I don't see `createHashHistory` defined anywhere in your code. It's unclear for me if you wanted to import it( maybe the `History` variable) or you wanted to use `createBrowserHistory` instead. Please clarify!

Comment: Sorry it should have been createBrowserHistory. I just updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no solution yet, find my (minimalistic) router version below, that is working for me.

**Dependencies:**

- react@15.1.0
- react-dom@15.1.0
- react-router@2.4.0

History.js is not needed explicitly, since it is a dependency of react-router.

**Webpack**
Make sure to add

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

to your webpack.config.js, since webpack-dev-server might have some issues routing correctly (mostly in terms of backwards navigation).

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

import {Routes} from './Routes'; // your routes file

render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        {Routes}
    </Router>,
    document.querySelector('#smartadmin-root')
);
```

I would encourage you to try this code and leave out your hotloading stuff.
Let me know if it helps and if there are any questions. I'm glad to edit my post as needed.