# The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`. in Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to ReactJs. This is my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
var Main = require('Main');
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Main}></Route>
</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and compiling it with webpack. Also I added Main component to my aliases. 
The console throws these errors: 
[image]
I also read these links :

[React Router failed prop 'history', is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845303/react-router-failed-prop-history-is-undefined)

[How do I resolve history is marked required, when value is undefined?](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-do-i-resolve-history-is-marked-required-when-value-is-undefined)

[Upgrading React-Router and replacing hashHistory with browserHistory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355265/upgrading-react-router-and-replacing-hashhistory-with-browserhistory)

and many searches around the web, but I couldn't fix this issue. React Router is version 4

Answer (score 188, accepted):

If you are using react-router v4 you need to install react-router-dom as well. After that, import BrowserRouter from react-router-dom and switch Router for BrowserRouter. It seems that v4 change several things. Also, the react-router documentation is outdated. This is my working code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render((
     <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/" component={App}/>
     </BrowserRouter>
     ),
     document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42895076/3943197)

Comment: In version 4,when you are using 'react-router-dom', there is no need to import 'react-router'. 'react-router-dom' is complete.

Comment: If I have multiple <Route ...> tags inside BrowserRouter I get this error: "Uncaught Error: A <Router> may have only one child element". How to fix?

Comment: @olefrank Yeah I had the same problem.. I fixed adding a <div> that wrappes all <Route /> components.. I'm learning as well and maybe isn't the best solution..

Comment: Question @Mammad2c . Do you need both `react-router` and `react-router-dom` in your node modules if you are saying to only import `react-router-dom`? If I am trying to use `react-router` v4 then why use `react-router-dom`? thx.

Comment: @erp react-router-dom has more options than react-router. you could visit the document. But you have only use one of them.

Comment: @erp Yes you will need both, as you'll need `route` from `react-router` and `HashRouter as Router` from `react-router-dom`.  You want to use the HashRouter, for some reason `Router` from `react-router` doesn't work.

Comment: @NSCoder no, router also is in the 'react-router-dom' so there is no need to include both 'react-router-dom' and 'react-router'. If you need 'HashRouter' and 'router' together, you have to include 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: @olefrank you need to wrap your multiple `<Route...>` statements in `<switch>` wrapper instead of wrapping them in `<div>`. If you use `<div>`, this makes the routes inclusive, which means if a path can match two routes, both components will render.  See full detail here: https://medium.com/@djoepramono/react-router-4-gotchas-2ecd1282de65

Comment: But I cannot have `history={history}` when using BrowserRouter, so I am not sure how is this the solution :/

Answer (score 20):

Which version of React Router are you using?   Router version 4 changed from passing in the browserHistory class to passing an instance of browserHistory, see the [code example in the new docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object).

This has been catching lots people who automatically upgrade; a migration document will be out 'any day now'.

You want to add this to the top:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

const newHistory = createBrowserHistory();
```

and

```
<Router history={newHistory}/>
```

Comment: version 4. Could you convert my code to version 4, please?

Comment: where is `customHistory` defined ?

Comment: sorry.  better now?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have **multiple routes** you can use switch like this,

```
import {Switch} from 'react-router';
```

then

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/" component={TodoComponent} />
         <Route path="/about" component={About} />
     </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem in ES6, but when I switched to use 'react-router-dom' library, the problem was solved. For all fans of ES6, here we go:

`npm install --save react-router-dom`

In index.js:

```
import {HashRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </HashRouter>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: `In index.js:` or `In index.jsx:` ?

Comment: @RazGalstyan index.js if you are using webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Version 4 of React Router changed several things. They made separate top level router elements for the different history types. If you're using version 4 you should be able to replace `<Router history={hashHistory}>` with `<HashRouter>` or `<BrowserRouter>`.
For more detail, see https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides

Answer (score 1):

For (year 2022) version "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0" if anyone is still facing this issue check the order of import in App.js file.

`import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'`

I don't know why the order matters but it worked for me.

Also this might help: [Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom/69968165#69968165)

Answer (score 0):

I also write a Login practice. And also meet the same question like you. After a day struggle, I found that only `this.props.history.push('/list/')` can make it instead of pulling in a lot of plugins. By the way, the `react-router-dom` version is `^4.2.2`. Thanks!

```js
handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err,values)=>{
        if(!err){
            this.setState({
                visible:false
            });
            this.props.form.resetFields();
            console.log(values.username);
            const path = '/list/';
            this.props.history.push(path);
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me with "react-router@^3.0.5":

package.json:

```
"react-dom": "^16.6.0",
"react-router": "^3.0.5"
```

index.js:

```
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { App } from './components/App'
import { NotFound404 } from './components/NotFound404'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={App} />
        <Route path='*' component={NotFound404} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```