# Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.

#### Index.js

```
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Sstore from './store/configureStore.js';
import routes from './routes';
import {loadMovies} from './actions/movieActions.js';

const store = Sstore;

store.dispatch(loadMovies());

render(  
      <Provider store={store}>

        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('app')
);
```

#### Route.js

```
import React from 'react';  
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';  
import Home from './components/Home.js';  

export default (  
      <Route path="/" component={Home}>

      </Route>
);
```

Comment: Your code is using the api from react-router 2/3. look here for the v4 docs https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: you will find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008036/the-prop-history-is-marked-as-required-in-router-but-its-value-is-undefine

Comment: @abdul I want to use with store

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux#usage) to react-router-redux v4 example. You have to use `ConnectedRouter` from react-router-redux and pass `history`. I configured my project yesterday based on this example and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In React router v4, your configuration should  be something like below.

```
 import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

 <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/api/:id" component={ComponentOne} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
```

The API has been changed since the previous version. Also note that the order matters. Keep the most specific paths at the top.

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I get rid of this type of error in two steps:

1. step in to import import  createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'; and declaring const   customHistory = createBrowserHistory(); like this:

   ```
   import  { BrowserRouter as StaticRouter, Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
   import  createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
   const   customHistory = createBrowserHistory();
   ```
2. It looks like that it is necessary to add history attribute to the Router:

   ```
   <Router history={customHistory}>
   <div>
       <Link to={'/.../' + linkName1}>
           {itemName1}
       </Link>
       <Link to={'/.../' + linkName2}>
           {itemName2}
       </Link>
   </div>
   ```