# Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs

I don't know why I am getting this error and I can't find an answer for it anywhere. I have uninstalled the `react-router-dom` package and reinstalled it, but it continues to tell me that the switch module is not exported from react-router-dom. Here's my code.

The error I'm getting:

> Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

#### Code

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from './components/navbar.js';
import Footer from './components/footer.js';
import Home from './components/pages/homepage/home.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app-container">
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: might be a caching issue from a service worker. try ctrl+f5 or browsing in incognito mode

Comment: FYI: Here is the question regarding `withRouter` being not exported: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66465750/630364

Answer (score 1336):

In *react-router-dom* v6, "Switch" is replaced by routes "Routes". You need to update the import from

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

You also need to update the Route declaration from

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

to

```
<Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
```

In *react-router-dom*, you also do not need to use the **exact** in the Route declaration.

For more information, you can visit the official documentation:
[upgrade to react-router-dom v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5)

Comment: Attention to the change `Home` to `<Home/>`, I didn't notice it at first look.

Comment: Also attention to `Route`s having `exact`, that prop was kind of removed.

Comment: Does anyone know the rationale for these changes to react-router-dom?

Comment: Oh, yeah! It perfectly answers the question. However, make sure to notice the change in component to 'element', otherwise will result in a silent warning in the browser console                   
                                                                                                                           
"Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page."

Comment: Unfortunately, this broke my code. See here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049211/changing-switch-routes-and-redirect-navigate-broke-protected-hoc-route. Looks like I'll go back to using version 5.

Comment: Componet does not work. Replace with element

Comment: I wonder why we do not need `exact`. If `Routers` behaves like the old `Switch` (going down the list of paths and render whatever it sees matches partially, without exact) then if I put my homepage with path "/" as a Route before my about page with path "/about", even with `url/about`, I think homepage will be rendered?

Comment: for me it worked but I changed  `component={}` to `Component={Home}`

Answer (score 244):

If you are using `react-router-dom` v6, it looks like `Switch` has been replaced with `Routes`.

Answer (score 184):

This is an example using react-router-dom V6

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

import '../styles/global.css'

import Layout from '../containers/Layout'
import Home from '../pages/Home'
import Login from '../containers/Login'
import RecoveryPassword from '../containers/RecoveryPassword'
import NotFound from '../pages/NotFound'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/recovery-password" element={<RecoveryPassword/>}/>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Within Route exact is throwing error @jean

Comment: This does not work for me. It says it cannot find "Routes". All the other bits import OK. react-router-dom i am using is 6.2.1

Comment: If you use typescript you discover that exact is no longer need in v6 because it is default. Standard JavaScript just ignores the extra parameter but TypeScript will complain.

Comment: Missed BrowserRouter in my case

Answer (score 119):

I also faced the same problem, and I searched towards the Internet so much, but I didn't get any answer according to my question.

So I uninstalled the version 6 of react-router-dom:

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
```

And installed version 5.2.0 of react-router-dom:

```
npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

Comment: This work perfectly , among all the answer this is the easiest way of doing by downgrading react-router-dom to 5.2.0 , but in my opinion we need to know the new syntax as well . Thanks

Comment: Best to install latest v5 so you don't run into [issues with React 18 and the `React.StrictMode` component](/a/71833424/8690857), e.g. `npm install react-router-dom@5`.

Answer (score 68):

Syntax has changed

Old Syntax

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

New Syntax:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Routes>
    <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: what about `Redirect`?

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh They replaced `Redirect` with `Navigate`

Comment: I like that you are mention that the old syntax and the new one, that help me to under stand the changes

Answer (score 35):

In react-router-dom v6, Switch has been replaced with Routes.
Use this format:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<component />} />
        <Route exact path="/path2" element={<component2 />} />
        <Route exact path="/path3" element={<component3 />} />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: Talk about rescuing me in the nick of time.  Thanks!

Comment: `"react-router-dom": "^6.2.2"` does not support prop `component` on Route Component.

Answer (score 33):

**If you are using version 6 of react-router-dom, use this**

Also, please see here for reference : [https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#:~:text=single%20route%20config%3A-,//%20This%20is%20a%20React%20Router%20v6%20app,%7D,-This%20step%20is](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#:%7E:text=single%20route%20config%3A-,//%20This%20is%20a%20React%20Router%20v6%20app,%7D,-This%20step%20is)

```
// This is a React Router v6 app
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="users" element={<Users />}>
          <Route path="me" element={<OwnUserProfile />} />
          <Route path=":id" element={<UserProfile />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function Users() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link to="me">My Profile</Link>
      </nav>

      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Component doesn't work but element does. This works for me in 2022.

Answer (score 20):

I was able to fix it by changing from Switch to Routes.
So you should have something like this:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/home' element={<Home/>} />
</Routes>
```

And also you need to change the import from Switch to Routes:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 16):

`react-router-dom` has updated to version 6. Now they have renamed the **`<Switch/>`** component to **`<Routes/>`**. There are also many changes.

You should spend sometime to read the documentation. Here is the link for [react-router-v6-doc](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/overview).

Comment: I followed a quick guide for v5 and got the same error.
v6 doc is here:
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/tutorial.md

Answer (score 15):

`<Switch>` is replaced by `<Routes>`

Before:

```
import { Route, Switch} from 'react-router'

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route />
        <Route />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Now:

```
import { Route, Routes} from 'react-router'

<Router>
    <Routes>
        <Route />
        <Route />
    </Routes>
</Router>
```

Just use Routes instead of Switch.

Answer (score 11):

Change from

```javascript
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

to

```javascript
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

<Routes>
    <Route path="/home" element={ <Home />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using an old application code with the new version and this was the issue.

Answer (score 11):

Step 1: Upgrade to `react` 16.8+ and `react-router-dom` v5.2:

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
npm install react-router-dom@5.2
```

Step 2: Update the `react-router-dom` import statement.

Change `import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";` to:

```js
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Step 3: Upgrade the syntax and replace "Switch" with "Routes" and "component" with "element"

Change

```js
<Switch>
    <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
</Switch>
```

to

```js
<Routes>
    <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage/>} />
</Routes>
```

Alternatively you can also downgrade the react-router-version as suggested in other solutions.

However, rather than going backwards, I would suggest to upgrade to latest version of react-router-dom and its syntax.

Answer (score 10):

`Switch` is exported from `react-router` and not `react-router-dom` (the same goes for `Route` I think).

Comment: React Router Dom has its own components and API https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start - here's a github issue to elaborate on the "differences" https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4648

Comment: @kJs0 you are right, I forgot `react-router-dom` re-exports everything from `react-router`.

Comment: this actually did fix my error, i installed the react-router package and imported it via react-router, but now I am getting another error stating "Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>", when my switch is definitely inside of a router? Lol

Comment: Make sure both version are exactly the same `react-router` & `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 10):

I solved my error by changing the way I was rendering my routes to the use of the `element`.

To:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./app";
import { Login, Register } from "./auth";
const R: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" caseSensitive={false} element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" caseSensitive={false} element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/" caseSensitive={false} element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default R;
```

Basically before `v6.*`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./app";
import { Login, Register } from "./auth";
const R: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
           <Login />
        </Route>
       <Route path="/register">
           <Register/>
        </Route>

       <Route path="/">
           <Home/>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default R;
```

After `v6.*`

```js
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { Home } from "./app";
import { Login, Register } from "./auth";
const R: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" caseSensitive={false} element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" caseSensitive={false} element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/" caseSensitive={false} element={<Home />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
};
export default R;
```

Answer (score 10):

In *react-router-dom* v6 **Switch is Replaced with Routes**.

And **component** with **element**

**{componentName} with {}**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is repeating previous answers, e.g. [Sridhar Rajaram's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom/70003931#70003931).

Answer (score 9):

What is your react-router-dom version?

```
"react-router": "^5.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

If it is above one then you need to remove node-modules and reinstall node-module using `npm install --save`.

Answer (score 9):

Write `<Routes>` instead of `<Switch>`.

Run this in the terminal:

```
npm install --save react-router react-router-dom
```

This helped me. Or check file *package.json* and add the following right after `"react-dom": "^17.0.2",`:

```
 "react-router": "^6.0.0",
```

Comment: Thanks. Below is my code and work.

Comment: import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Transcript from './Transcript';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="content">
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path ="/" element={ <Transcript /> } />
            <Route path ="/Transcript" element={ <Transcript /> } />
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;

Comment: 3/24/2023 - this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

You have to check npm package version first.
To check, run `npm info react-router-dom version`.

If the package version is >= 6.0.0, you have to change

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

And also have to change

```
<Route path="/home" component={Home} />
```

to

```
<Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `react-router-dom` v6, you have to change Switch to Routes as given in the example below:

Instead of importing Switch,
`import { Switch, ... } from 'react-router-dom';`

import Routes
`import { Routes, ...} from 'react-router-dom';`

Then, instead of using `component = {ComponentName}, use element={<ComponentName/>}` as shown below:

```
import { Routes, Route, ...} from 'react-router-dom';
    .
    .
    .  
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/' element={<Home/>}></Route>
    </Routes>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using version 6 of react-router-dom, then you need to update `Switch` with `Routes`. The below syntax worked for me:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. On the project terminal, type the following commands. You will not need to make any changes to your code.

1. `npm uninstall react-router-dom`
2. `npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0`

Comment: I would never suggest to downgrade. Expecially not a major downgrade. Might be a quick fix but it's dirty.

Answer (score 6):

Switch has been replaced by Routes.

Source from *[Update routing (react-router-dom syntax) #1386](https://github.com/howtographql/howtographql/pull/1386)*  (howtographql GitHub)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
import {
      BrowserRouter as Router,
      Routes,
      Route,
      Link
    } from "react-router-dom";
    
    function App() {
      return (
        <>
        <Router className="App">
          <Navbar/>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/'>
    
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem like this:

```
yarn add react-router-dom@5,3,0
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution:

Delete the [node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294260/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-node-modules-folder) folder. In the *package.json* file, change the react-router-dom version (version 6 in my case) to `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.1"`

Then in the terminal run:

`npm install` to install the dependencies and then run
`npm start` to relaunch

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a newer version of `react-router-dom` (for example,  ^6.2.1 in my case) you should change `<Switch>` to `<Routes>` and use `<Route>` with the `component={<SampleComponent />}` parameter.

Particularly the code example below:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import MyComponent from './containers/MyComponent';

export default function AppRoutes() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" component={<MyComponent />}>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you installed *react-router* and *react-router-dom v6 beta*, just uninstall like this:

```
npm uninstall --save react-router react-router-dom
```

And install it with this:

```
npm install --save react-router react-router-dom
```

It is going to install the latest version that is not beta.

Then we just need to restart Visual Studio Code or whichever text editor you handle it with.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually not a problem with you or React or your code. It's just the updated version of react-router-dom. Replace the Switch by Routes.

That’s it. Just use Routes instead of Switch and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

In `react-router-dom` v6, the `switch` is replaced by the `Routes`. Below is the simple example to configure `react-router-dom` v6.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Layout from './components/Layout';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';
import LoginPage from './pages/LoginPage';
import WizardPage from './pages/WizardPage';
import RequestsPage from './pages/RequestsPage';

import './App.scss'

export class App extends React.Component {
    public render() {
        const sharedRouteProps = { exact: true, authenticationPath: '/login' };
        const wizardRouteProps = { ...sharedRouteProps, path: "/", component: WizardPage };
        const requestsRouteProps = { ...sharedRouteProps, path: "/requests", component: RequestsPage };

        return (
            <Layout>
              <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={LoginPage} />
                    <ProtectedRoute {...wizardRouteProps} />
                    <ProtectedRoute {...requestsRouteProps} />
                </Switch>
              </Router>
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply have to do two things:

1. Replace Switch with Routes.
2. Use this Route tag

```
<Route path="/" element={<Component />} />
```

instead of this one:

```
<Route>
  path="/"
  <Component />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 3):

use **Routes** instead of **Switch** if you are using react-router-dom version6

Answer (score 3):

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import App from "./App";
const RouterPage = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    <Link to="/posts">Posts</Link>
                    <Link to="/">About</Link>
                    <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                </nav>
                <Routes>
                    <Route exact path="/" element={<App />}></Route>
                    <Route path="/post" element={<App />} />
                    <Route path="/about" element={<App />} />
                    <Route path="/contact" element={<App />} />
                </Routes>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

**you should replace Switch to Routes**

Answer (score 2):

I got this error after installing **react-router-dom v6.0.2.**

Replacing *Switch* with *Routes* solved the issue:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from "react-router-dom";
```

Answer (score 2):

There has been a breaking change in the `react-router-dom` package recently. [React Router v6 Changelog Permalink](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes)

So all you need is to rename the import like so...

```
import { Routes as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In version 6 of react-router-dom, switch is no longer used and instead you can use the following example:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

```
import { store } from './redux/store.js'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import { Form } from "./component/Form/Form"
import { Navbar } from "./component/Navbar/Navbar"

import { Home } from "./pages/Home/Home"
import { AboutUs } from "./pages/AboutUs/AboutUs"
import { Products } from "./pages/Products/Products"
import { NotFound } from "./pages/NotFound/NotFound"
import { Dashboard } from "./pages/Dashboard/Dashboard"
import { PrivateRoute } from "./pages/PrivateRoute"

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Navbar />
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Form />} />
                    <Route path="/" element={<Form />} />
                    <Route path="/products" element={<Products />} />
                    <Route path="/about-us" element={<AboutUs />} />
                    <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    )
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 1):

In 'react-dom V6' Switch is not exist. Instead of 'Switch' , 'Routes' should use`import { Routes } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: It's already stated by the most upvoted answer (and all the other answers in fact) except it gives more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and I have removed `react-router-dom` and then reinstalled it.

The issue occurred because I have upgraded it to the latest version, i.e., react-router-dom v6 and then wanted to downgrade to the previous version, i.e., v5.

I was on Ruby on Rails project and using yarn to manage dependency you can use this command to remove and reinstall it:

`yarn remove react-router-dom`

`yarn add react-router-dom`

This should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue as the issue poster. I tried all things like below:

- uninstall and install react-router-dom
- separately imported Switch from react-router-dom

But nothing really worked for me.

Kindly follow the below instructions. I am sure you will not get the error again.

Correct code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import NavBar from "./components/navbar.js";
import Footer from "./components/footer.js";
import Home from "./components/pages/homepage/home.js";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app-container">
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Note: Switch have been replaced with Routes and instead of using component, we need to use *element*.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing that issue and finally solved it, by arranging code. I am very new in React.

Following is my *App.js* code (class base component):

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import News from './components/News';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes,Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar/>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/general"><News pageSize={3} country={'us'} category={'general'}/></Route>
          </Routes>
        </Router>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

1st Method [replace Switch with Routes]

```
import { Routes , Route , Link } from 'react-router-dom';
<Routes>
 <Route exact path='/'>
  <HomePage />
 </Route>
</Routes>
```

2nd Method [downgrade your react-router-dom version to version 5 or below]

```
npm i react-router-dom@5.0.0
```