# Compiled with problems:X ERROR in ./src/route/AppRoute.js 12:37-43 export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

> Compiled with problems:X
> ERROR in ./src/route/AppRoute.js 12:37-43
> export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router' (possible exports: MemoryRouter, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createRoutesFromChildren, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes)

My source code for using React:

[image]

In the command line the error shows up like so:

[image]

The items available in the folder are:

[image]

I tried googling and used this command, but still its not working and showing the same error as I said earlier:

command i tried to use but still facing the same issue:

[image]

Can you please provide me with what to do step by step?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've accidentally upgraded/installed the latest version of `react-router-dom`, version 6. You've two options from here:

1. Downgrade/revert back to version v5.x

   Uninstall any current versions of `react-router-dom` and `react-dom`, and then install a specific v5 version of them.

   From your project directory run:

   - ```
     npm un -s react-router-dom react-dom
     ```
   - ```
     npm i -s react-router-dom@5.3.0 react-dom@5.3.0
     ```
2. Complete/apply the v5 migration guide

   [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

   If you decide to move forward with the migration then you'll likely want to uninstall `react-router` since `react-router-dom` re-exports all the exports from `react-router`, or at a minimum you want to ensure it's on the same version.

   Uninstall:

   ```
   npm un -s react-router
   ```

   Or reinstall latest of each:

   - ```
     npm un -s react-router-dom react-router
     ```
   - ```
     npm i -s react-router-dom@latest react-router@latest
     ```

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom v6, "Switch" is replaced by routes "Routes". You need to update the import from

`import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";`
to
`import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';`