# Getting blank page on using Route | React

Tags: reactjs

guys!

I'm having some kind of trouble when adding a simple /home route to my app. When i add the line below to my App.js, the app turns blank (even the NavBar vanishes):

```
        <Route path='/home' exact component={HomeScreen} />
```

No compiling or server errors.

Can u give me a light?

### App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path='/home' exact component={HomeScreen} />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### HomeScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
      <div>
        <h1>asdasdHome Screen</h1>
      </div>
  )
}

export default HomeScreen
```

### Tree

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUi0q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
mport { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
           <Route path='/home' element={<HomeScreen/>} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The bit that wasnt working was where you defined your element so change

```
 <Route path='/home' exact component={HomeScreen} />
```

to this

```
 <Route path='/home' element={<HomeScreen/>} />
```

Comment: got this: export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: BrowserRouter, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, Navigate, Outlet, Route, Router, Routes, UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext, createRoutesFromChildren, createSearchParams, generatePath, matchPath, matchRoutes, renderMatches, resolvePath, unstable_HistoryRouter, useHref, useInRouterContext, useLinkClickHandler, useLocation, useMatch, useNavigate, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext, useParams, useResolvedPath, useRoutes, useSearchParams)

Comment: @Diego In your package.json please confirm which version of react-router-dom you are using

Comment: on other post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom) they said it was replaced by "Routes". Using "Routes" gives me no more blank page, but doesn't render the home screen element.

Comment: "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",

Comment: @Diego Sorry just updated my answer for the new version of react-router-dom. Same as S.marx answer

Answer (score 0):

Hey Diego now there is **react router v6**

Where **Switch** is replaced for **Routes** and `component={HomeScreen}` for `element={<HomeScreen/>}`

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar/>
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
           <Route path='/home' element={<HomeScreen/>} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Solved! Tyvm =)

Answer (score 0):

I think u used Link in Navbar. And the navbar is outside the broweser router. This was my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).