# 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYFni.png*)

**Please Solve this Issue in react js Project**

I am running project in local.

Comment: Please share relevant code and react-router-dom version that you are using

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the react-router-dom version you're using doesn't have that export anymore:

[Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom)

You can either downgrade react-router-dom to a lower version in your package.json by running the following commands:

```
npm uninstall react-router-dom
npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0
```

or by migrating to the new API (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69880162/19461620))