# Problem with react router dom cannot connect link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

got error while doing react router dom
error is "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')"

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

Comment: You show use the `useRef ` error but your code doesn't have `useRef` anywhere.

Comment: Hi @chester Thapa, you need to show your whole code.

Answer (score 1):

According to that answer: [**import error switch is not exported**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom.)

`Switch` is replaced by routes `Routes`. In newer version of `react-router-dom`. So, you need syntax like that:

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
```

to

```
import { Routes ,Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

And if it is not the case, then you need to check your router package version.

#### Upgrade all `<Switch>` elements to `<Routes>`

- React Router v6 introduces a Routes component that is kind of like Switch, but a lot more powerful. The main advantages of Routes over Switch are:
- All `<Route>s` and `<Link>s` inside a `<Routes>` are relative. This leads to leaner and more predictable code in `<Route path>` and `<Link to>`
- Routes are chosen based on the best match, instead of being traversed in order. This avoids bugs due to unreachable routes because they were defined later in your `<Switch>`
- Routes may be nested in one place instead of being spread out in different components. In small to medium-sized apps, this lets you easily see all your routes at once. In large apps, you can still nest routes in bundles that you load dynamically via `React.lazy`
- In order to use **v6**, you'll need to convert all your `<Switch>` elements to . If you already made the upgrade to **v5.1**, you're halfway there.
- Here is the official documentation link: [**upgrade all switch elements to routes**](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#upgrade-all-switch-elements-to-routes)

Comment: you can also write `import { Routes as Switch, … } from "react-router-dom"`

Comment: still got an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')"