# Hi, Every time when I use react router dom in my react app it got stuck

Tags: reactjs, react-router, switch-statement, react-router-dom

Every time when I use react router dom in my react app it get stucks on switch export

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js 19:39-45 export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was 
not found in 'react-router-dom' (possible exports: AbortedDeferredError, 
Await, BrowserRouter, Form, HashRouter, Link, MemoryRouter, NavLink, 
Navigate, NavigationType, Outlet, Route, Router, RouterProvider, Routes, 
ScrollRestoration, UNSAFE_DataRouterContext, UNSAFE_DataRouterStateContext, 
UNSAFE_LocationContext, UNSAFE_NavigationContext, UNSAFE_RouteContext,
 UNSAFE_useRouteId, UNSAFE_useScrollRestoration, 

createBrowserRouter, createHashRouter, createMemoryRouter, createPath, createRoutesFromChildren, createRoutesFromElements, createSearchParams, 
defer, generatePath, isRouteErrorResponse, json, matchPath, matchRoutes, parsePath, redirect, redirectDocument, renderMatches, resolvePath, 
unstable_HistoryRouter, unstable_useBlocker, unstable_usePrompt, useActionData, useAsyncError, useAsyncValue, useBeforeUnload, useFetcher, useFetchers, useFormAction, useHref, useInRouterContext, 
useLinkClickHandler, useLoaderData, useLocation, useMatch, useMatches, 
useNavigate, useNavigation, useNavigationType, useOutlet, useOutletContext,
 useParams, useResolvedPath, useRevalidator, useRouteError, 
useRouteLoaderData, useRoutes, useSearchParams, useSubmit)
```

I tried alot but nothing found

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add some code

Comment: have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124161/attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router-dom) "Switch" was replaced by "Routes" in react-router-dom since v6. You need to change your imports from `import { Switch } from "react-router-dom";` to `import { Routes } from "react-router-dom";`

Answer (score 0):

check your package.json, you use react-routerV6 instead react-routerV5 who let use Switch.So you can change pckg or use Routes.