# Express and Apache - ENOENT on callback

Tags: node.js, apache, reactjs, express, auth0

I'm trying to run a React webapp I made on an Apache server using Express.
The app is using routes on the front-end (using hashHistory).
Everythinbg works a charm locally.
It all seems a bit more problematic on my production server, with my authentication library (Auth0) trying to make a call back to one of the front-end routes that throws a 404 with the following error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/dist/index.html'
at Error (native)
```

My virtual host entry is as follows:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName domain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/folder

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyVia Full
        <Proxy *>
                Require all granted
        </Proxy>

        <Location /*>
                ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000
                ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            # changed from None to FileInfo
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

This is the directory structure in place:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── 22163591c40fdf91545d26bca737a727.png
│   ├── 448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2
│   ├── 89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg
│   ├── e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf
│   ├── f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot
│   ├── fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── nb-utm-tagging-tool.1.0.0.css
│   └── nb-utm-tagging-tool.1.0.0.js
└── serve.js
```

And this is my Express server:

```
    var express = require('express')
    var app = express()

    var path = require('path');

    app.use(express.static('dist'))

    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(9000, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 9000!')
    })
```

When I launch the app, there's a call to the Auth0 API to try to authenticate the user but it fails with the above error message.

I should add that while /login is unavailable, /#/login does indeed get you somewhere. Not sure why or what it means.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Anyone able to help?

Comment: Can you show us the full directory structure and the URL/address you're trying to access?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question above. Thanks!

Comment: Do you Angular as front-end?

Comment: I used React, with hashHistory for managing routes.

Comment: Darn, I've never player with React, but I suspect your trouble is there.
Go have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. I think I solved it, see answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this thanks to @pierre-r-a's suggestion.

I read this, which is a great guide for what I was trying to do:
[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually)

I simply added this to my config file for the virtual host and it's all smooth now.

```
<Location /login>
            ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:9000
            ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:9000
</Location>
```