# Redirect Hash URL to standard URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hash, redirect, window.location

I have an URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/contrat?id=8171675304
```

And I'm trying to redirect it to:

```
http://localhost:3000/contrat?id=8171675304
```

I tried the following:

```
window.location.assign(hash.replace('#/', ''));
```

And this code too :     `window.location.replace(hash.replace('#/', ''));`

Both of these solutions doesn't redirect as intended & the page end up in `http://localhost:3000`

## Edit:

When I copy & paste the URL both of solutions above work! But when I click on the link(    http://localhost:3000/#/contrat?id=8171675304 ) on the browser it redirects to http://localhost:3000

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop /#/ in browser with react-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router)

Comment: @JordiNebot already tried the solution. It doesn't work in my case. I don't want to use HashRouter!

Answer (score 0):

Try this please !

```
.replace( /#.*/, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had in mind something like:

```
window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace('#/',''))
```

But with your most recent edit about not working when you click, you might want [a different approach](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_redirect_webpage.asp) for that part:

```
// Simulate a mouse click:
window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

// Simulate an HTTP redirect:
window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
```

All that being said, I'm quite new to JS, so it might not be the best way to do it.