# Why on react history createHashHistory appends /# for each path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, history.js

I have an application with this config for history:

```js
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

const history = createHashHistory({
  hashType: 'slash',
});
    ...
  <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <App />
  </ConnectedRouter>
```

But all my routes get appended by `/#`
ex: `localhost:8080/` becomes: `localhost:8080/#/`

I already tried to update my packages as [this question say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25086832/how-to-stop-in-browser-with-react-router) but it didn't work.

The only thing that worked was change `createHashHistory` to `createBrowserHistory`, but I'm not sure what's the difference between them, and why `createHashHistory` is appending the `/#`

Comment: Hash routing in general is UI routing that contains a `/#/`. It utilizes the `hashchange` and `window.location.hash` API to simulate routing. Alternately, UI routing uses the `history` API to update the URL and store previous states in browser memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With hashHistory, it produces url like
http://yourwebsite.net/#page/xxx

With browserHistory, it produces url like
http://yourwebsite.net/page/xxx

Which one to use? In real-world products, browserHistory is mostly used. A rule of thumb is "if you are using a dynamic server that can handle dynamic URLs then you need to use the BrowserRouter component but if you are using a server that only serves static files then a HashRouter component is what to be used in this case."

In your code, hashType: 'slash' is just the default value.

Comment: Thank you, just one thing:`hashType: 'slash'` is the default value for what?

Comment: I mean, you can simply use createHashHistory(), instead of createHashHistory({
  hashType: 'slash',
});